# SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime and Find Max Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to find max date from a `DATE` column, the column format is `YYYY-MM` and its of type `varchar`.

```
DATE
--------
2020-07     (I try to find this value)
2020-06 
2020-05
2020-04
```

I tried with the following SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, 'DATE') AS Date 
FROM
    DateTable
```

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'DATE')  as Date From DateTable

Comment: Rule #1 : do **NOT** store dates as `varchar` !! SQL Server has specific `DATE` and `DATETIME2(n)` datatypes - **use them!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below way -

```
select max(cast(concat(columnName,'-01') as date))
from yourtable
```

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir, if it helped u then mark it as accepted answer, and with your new requirement post another question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select Top 1 Column_Name from table_Name order by Column_Name desc
*//here replace Column_Name by column that contains dates*
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
select left(convert(varchar,max(concat([date],'-01'))),7) maxDate
from DateTable
```